# Office UI Fabric - DetailsList and clickable column

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I was wondering how to format the DetailsList so that a certain column renders a clickable link, just like OneDrive and SharePoint Online do for the filename. Is this a custom renderer function for that column that returns a  component or is this a prop I can pass to the DetailsList component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find detailed information along with some code samples at this location: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/detailslist/customitemcolumns

To answer your question: `onRenderItemColumn` is the prop which gives you the custom renderer to wrap the content of a specific column in anything you want (check the link above to see how).